Running Webots Controller together with ROS2 sensor plugins from webots_ros2
I have a robot setup in webots that ros2_control does not support out-of-the-box. Therefore I have written my own Webots controller (based on https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/controller-programming) that allows me to control the robot's locomotion. lets name this controller "Alpha"
With that, I have continued to add sensors to my robot in webots (lidar, imu and camera). I then followed the webots_ros2 wiki https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/wiki/References-Devices#sensor-devices to add ROS2 interface plugins for my added sensors.
However,running my simulation i discovered that when i select the "<extern>" controller, the sensor plugins will run but my "Alpha" controller will no longer work, and vice-versa if i selected the "Alpha" controller instead.
Does anyone know how I can make both function together in the simulation?
